# how to take variable from different `def()` function to another - python

Tags: python, numpy

I have two different functions like :

```
def messageWindow():
    # all the necessary operations
    feature_matrix_db = zip( B_mean , G_mean , R_mean, cont_list , ene_list , homo_list , cor_list, dis_list)
    return feature_matrix_db

def open():
    #all the necessary operations
    feature_matrix_ip = zip( B_mean1 , G_mean1 , R_mean1, cont_list1 , ene_list1 , homo_list1 , cor_list1 , dis_list1)
    return feature_matrix_ip

def result():
    COLUMNS = 12
    image_count = 0
    resultlist_key = []
    result_list = list()
    i = 0
    a_list = list()
    b_list = list()
    a_list.append(feature_matrix_ip)
    while i < 70:
        b_list.append(feature_matrix_db[i])
        dist = distance.euclidean(a_list,b_list[i])
        result_list.append(dist)
        resultlist_key = OrderedDict(sorted(enumerate(result_list),key=lambda x:x[0])).keys()
        i = i + 1 

    res_lst_srt = {'values': result_list,'keys':resultlist_key}
    res_lst_srt['values'], res_lst_srt['keys'] = zip(*sorted(zip(res_lst_srt['values'], res_lst_srt['keys'])))
    key = res_lst_srt['keys']

    for i1,val in enumerate(key):
        if i1 < 4:
            image_count += 1
            r, c = divmod(image_count, COLUMNS)
            im = Image.open(resizelist[val])
            tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized)
            myvar = Label(win, image=tkimage)
            myvar.image = tkimage
            myvar.grid(row=r, column=c)
```

First two `def()` function will return `feature_matrix_db` and `feature_matrix_ip`, and I want these results to be imported into the next `def()` function **result**. And it is giving an error like :

```
im = Image.open(resizelist[val])
File "E:\Canopy\System\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1956, in open
prefix = fp.read(16)
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't overwrite the builtin `open()` or you will have a bad time when you want to open a file.

Comment: @msvalkon okay I will change that `open()`

Comment: Please read about [functions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions) in python. You have no arguments to any of these functions *and* you are not declaring any of the variables inside the first two functions. You're never *calling* any of your functions inside the `result()`, thus the functions will never return the data.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to read up about namespacing and scoping in python. There's some info here: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html

For example your `messageWindow()` function:

```
def messageWindow():
    # all the necessary operations
    feature_matrix_db = zip( B_mean , G_mean , R_mean, cont_list , ene_list , homo_list , cor_list, dis_list)
    return feature_matrix_db
```

But where are `B_mean`, `G_mean`, `R_mean`, `cont_list`, `ene_list`, `homo_list`, `cor_list` and `dis_list` defined? You can pass them to `messageWindow()` as arguments:

```
def messageWindow(B_mean , G_mean , R_mean, cont_list , ene_list , homo_list , cor_list, dis_list):
    # all the necessary operations
    feature_matrix_db = zip( B_mean , G_mean , R_mean, cont_list , ene_list , homo_list , cor_list, dis_list)
    return feature_matrix_db
```

or assign some value to them within the function, or assign some value to them outside of the function using the `global` keyword. But you can't just call them without having ever said what values they take.

Let's look at the first few lines of `result()`:

```
def result():
    COLUMNS = 12
    image_count = 0
    resultlist_key = []
    result_list = list()
    i = 0
    a_list = list()
    b_list = list()
    a_list.append(feature_matrix_ip)
```

Again, where is `feature_matrix_ip` defined? What you could do instead is this:

```
feature_matrix_ip = open() #super bad idea to call your function open()
a_list.append(feature_matrix_ip)
```

Comment: `B_mean, G_mean,R_mean,cont_list , ene_list , homo_list , cor_list, dis_list` are declared and called in each of the functions i have specified.